# Calling setNeedsDisplay:YES on layer-hosting view does not redraw the view

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

I have a layer-hosting view set up like this in a custom `NSView` subclass:

```
[self setLayer:rootLayer];
[self setWantsLayer:YES];
```

I add all the sublayers to the layer tree after I called `setNeedsDisplay` on each sublayer. Each layer's content is provided by a `drawLayer:inContext` method of my layer's delegate.

Here is my problem:

After initializing my view the view gets draw correctly. However, when the model has changed and I call `[myCustomView setNeedsDisplay:YES];` from my view controller the `drawLayer:inContext` is not called.

I am confused now how to update the view:

- Do I have to call the `setNeedsDisplay` method on each CALayer in the layer tree?
- Should not the call of `setNeedsDisplay:YES` on the layer-hosting view itself trigger the redraw of the whole layer tree?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**

I have found something in the NSView Class reference

> A layer-backed view is a view that is backed by a Core Animation layer. Any drawing done by the view is the cached in the backing layer. You configured a layer-backed view by simply invoking setWantsLayer: with a value of YES. The view class will automatically create the a backing layer for you, and you use the view class’s drawing mechanisms. When using layer-backed views you should never interact directly with the layer.
>
> A layer-hosting view is a view that contains a Core Animation layer that you intend to manipulate directly. You create a layer-hosting view by instantiating an instance of a Core Animation layer class and setting that layer using the view’s setLayer: method. After doing so, you then invoke setWantsLayer: with a value of YES. When using a layer-hosting view you should not rely on the view for drawing, nor should you add subviews to the layer-hosting view.

[link to documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html)

In my case I have a layer-hosting view. So does that indeed mean that I have to trigger the redraw manually? Should I implement a pseudo drawRect method in the custom NSView to call the appropriate setNeedsDisplay on the CALayers that changed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After further research in Apple's [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CoreAnimationKioskStyleMenu/Introduction/Intro.html) of a kiosk-style menu I found out that if you are using a layer-hosting view, you have to take care of the screen updates which are neccessary due to model changes yourself. Calling `setNeedsDisplay:YES` on the NSView will not do anything.

So what one has to do if one has to update a view one should write a method like reloadData and in it one should call `setNeedsDisplay`on each CALayer that needs a refresh. I am still not sure if a call to this method on the root layer will propagate through all the children layers but I do not think so.

I solved the problem now by calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the individual CALayers that needed recaching. It works without problems.

Comment: Your link to the sample code is broken, perhaps this is the replacement: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CoreAnimationKioskStyleMenu/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009512

Answer (score 2):

There is also an oft-used practice of having an empty "drawrect", a la `-(void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {}` to help coerce things into drawing, *i believe* via good ole `view.needsDisplay = YES;`.

and it should be noted.. that what is indeed happening is that - by saying your `NSView *view;` is `layer.delegate = view;` causes the layer to be drawn when `[layer setNeedsDisplay];` is called.... via `- (void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {...}`..

along the same vein... when saying `layer.layoutManager = view`... subsequent demands that `[layer setNeedsLayout];` will be fulfilled only when the `- (void) layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer *)layer {..}` method is implemented..

These vital concepts are glossed over / strewn about in Apple's docs... and they are really so pivotal to making absolutely anything work at all.

Comment: can you explain a bit more beginner friendly way.

Comment: @carbonr I know it's confusing. But what I said is as simple as it gets. If things aren't displaying properly, and your view is the layer's delegate.. You need to implement `drawLayer:inContext` and maybe have an empty `drawRect:` AND call `setNeedsDisplay`. Read it 10 times if you have to, but the info is all there. If I recall correctly, that is. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically delegate the `setNeedsDispay:` by changing the redraw policy of the view. You have to assign `NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay` to the property `layerContentsRedrawPolicy` (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483514-layercontentsredrawpolicy). This will trigger redrawing of the layer when you send `setNeedsDisplay:` to the view:

```
[self setLayer:rootLayer];
[self setWantsLayer:YES];
self.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay;
```

or in Swift:

```
layer = rootLayer
wantsLayer = true
layerContentsRedrawPolicy = .onSetNeedsDisplay
```