# Forcing Core Plot plotArea fill to update

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-plot

I'm trying to toggle the fill for a **Core Plot** plot area on and off.  When I set up the fill at application launch everything works.  Toggling the first time works fine. Subsequent toggling of the fill on or off does not work unless a rotate the display.

```
-(void)layoutGraphPlotAreaFill{
    CPTFill *plotFill=nil;
    if (self.graphPlotAreaHasFill) {
        plotFill=self.graphPlotAreaFill;
    }else{
        plotFill=nil;
    }

    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.fill=plotFill;
}
```

I'm calling the above code from a settings view controller via a delegate method.  *NSLog* statements within the above method (removed) show that the method is being called, that the `graphPlotAreaHasFill` property is set correctly and the `CPTFill` is correct.  It just isn't updating the plotArea fill.  Again, it will only update after rotating the display.

Using **Core Plot 1.0**.

Any suggestions on how to force the update of the fill area without having to rotate?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the answer here:  [Calling setNeedsDisplay:YES on layer-hosting view does not redraw the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647914/calling-setneedsdisplayyes-on-layer-hosting-view-does-not-redraw-the-view)

turns out because the fill is a `CALayer` subclass, I can call `setNeedsDisplay` and it will refresh.  Update code is as follows:

```
-(void)layoutGraphPlotAreaFill{
    CPTFill *plotFill=nil;
    if (self.graphPlotAreaHasFill) {
       plotFill=self.graphPlotAreaFill;
    }else{
       plotFill=nil;
    }

    self.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.fill=plotFill;
    [self.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: That was a bug in Core Plot—it should redraw automatically. I've fixed this in the repository and it will be included in the next release. You can pull the latest code with Mercurial to get the change or continue to use your fix until you update to a new version of Core Plot.

Comment: @Eric, does this bug affect the graph.title property as well? Am having the same problem and only telling rotating or calling [graph setNeedsDisplay] fixes it.

Comment: The graph title should update when you set new title text. You shouldn't have to redraw the whole graph just to redraw the title.